# AngularJS on TideSDK outputs $locationWatch errors

Tags: angularjs, chromium, tidesdk

I am working on trying to implement an AngularJS project inside TideSDK. However, when running the program, I get the following errors:

> [09:15:57:982] [Ti.API] [Error] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 29; oldVal: 28"], ["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 30; oldVal: 29"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 31; oldVal: 30"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 32; oldVal: 31"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 33; oldVal: 32"]]

I attempted a fix related to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/mRIo8LaTh4M/dvV4y_SqvKEJ) but it has had no effect.

AFAIK, Tide is based on the latest Chromium. I imagined they would work well together.

This all started when I implmented the routing system in Angular.

Comment: not the same scenario as yours, but many are experiencing the same error on IE. See e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK is currently still using a very old version of webkit. It will be upgraded to the most recent version of webkit with TideSDK version 1.4, soon.

Comment: Doing the same thing here. Sure wish 1.4 was out :-)

Comment: Really disappointing to see how old this thread is. I have just run into the same problem with angularjs and tidesdk, more than a year later and 1.4 has not been released. Such a shame such a good project has been abandoned!

Comment: Yup, TideSDK is dead. It has been abandoned by the devs in favor of a properitary spin-off: http://tidekit.com